# The hairgrip is in her hair but on her head. Is it idiomatic to say "put in your hairgrip" or "put on your hairgrip"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

We say "**put on your hat**".

Similarly, can the word "**hairgrip**" be used like a hat, a T-shirt, etc?

The hairgrip is *in* her hair  but *on* her head.

Is it idiomatic to say "**put in your hairgrip**" (imply: in the hair) or "**put on your hairgrip**" (imply: on the head)?

Comment: I think either. If it's to keep her hair up, I'd say, "*put **in** your hairgrip*", but if she wears it as an accessory, I'd say, "*put **on** your hairgrip*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "in" works better.
If you use "on", it sounds like a single article of clothing.
Someone might use several hairpins in their hair; hairpins aren't like a single headband, where "on" might be better.